# Why is a "number" column with a calculated default value working for PDF and not for PPTX?

Tags: calculated-column

I have a column "Year" as number which is set to have a calculated default value:

```
=YEAR(Today)
```

It works when I upload PDF, but not PPTX.

What could cause the issue?

See all info here:

[image: aa]

Comment: Can you try: `=YEAR(Today())` **or** `=YEAR(NOW())`? Also, how are you uploading both files, using drag and drop or using upload option and then manually selecting the file?

Comment: @GaneshSanap manual upload or drag and drop have the same result. Testing those two suggestions also brings no improvement.